# Problem using `scanf()` with `%f` (avr-gcc)

Tags: c, floating-point, scanf, avr, avr-gcc

(Note: In an early version of this question I assumed that I used references the wrong way. It turned out to be a different problem and I made changes to the title/question accordingly.)

My code is intended to be compiled with `avr-gcc` and runs on an ATmega168p micocontroller.

I have the below function in C that is supposed to parse a float value from a buffer (char array) and assign it to a corresponsing float variable:

```
void read_float_from_buffer(float *var, char *buffer, uint8_t start, uint8_t end) {
    char val_buf[8];

    // transfer characters representing float to a temporary buffer
    uint8_t p=0;
    for (uint8_t i=start;i<=end && p<7;i++) {
        val_buf[p++]=buffer[i];
    }
    val_buf[p]='\0';

    // perform sscanf on this temporary buffer
    float buf=-1;
    if(sscanf(val_buf, "%.2f", &buf)==1) // this fails, sscanf returns 0
      *var=buf;
}
```

I have another function `find_float_in_buffer()` which searches a char buffer for the start and end indices of a float value. The function `read_float_from_buffer()` is called within this function:

```
float a_float_variable=0.;
void find_float_in_buffer(char *buffer) {
    uint8_t start,end=0;
    /*
    I do some magic here to find out where my float string starts and ends
    */
    read_buffer_float(&a_float_variable,buffer,start,end);
}
```

From my understanding this should work, but for some reason, scanning the `val_buf` temporary buffer fails (sscanf returns 0).

My question: is the way I'm passing the reference to `buffer` to `read_buffer_float` in `find_float_in_buffer` correct? I thought I finally understood how to pass pointers or references to functions, but I'm not sure if this is how you would pass a pointer in a function on to another function.

**Edit:** I'm running this code on a Atmel microcontroller and compiling using `avr-gcc`.

**Edit 2:** I removed my entire firmware and came up with the following MWE:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "src/peripheral-core/uart.c"

int main() {
  _delay_ms(200);
  uart_init();
  uartWriteString("application started\n\r\0");

  char test[]="12.34\0";
  float testfloat=-1;
  sscanf(test, "%f", &testfloat);

  uartWriteString("teststring is:\t\0");
  uartWriteString(test);
  uartWriteString("\n\rscanned float is:\t\0");
  uartWriteFloat(testfloat);
  uartWriteString("\n\0");

  for (;;) {
    _delay_ms(1000);
  }
}
```

For me, this prints:

```
application started

teststring is:  12.34

scanned float is:   -1.000
```

To build the `.hex` file I run this command:

```
avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -c -Os -Wall -mmcu=atmega168p main.c -o main.o
avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm -mmcu=atmega168p main.o -o main.elf
avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .data -j .text main.elf main.hex
```

AVR-GCC version:

`avr-gcc --version` gives `avr-gcc.exe (GCC) 10.1.0`

When I run the below equivalent on my developement system, it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("application started\n\r\0");

  char test[]="12.34\0";
  float testfloat=-1;
  sscanf(test, "%f", &testfloat);

  printf("teststring is:\t\0");
  printf(test);
  printf("\n\rscanned float is:\t\0");
  printf("%.2f",testfloat);
  printf("\n\0");
}
```

**But:** When I pass `"%.2f"` to `sscanf()` as a format specifier (which is invalid as pointed out in the comments), this version fails with the same behaviour.

Comment: Try printing `val_buf` after populating it to make sure it contains what you expect.  Also, there's no precision field in `scanf` formats.

Comment: `I do some magic here`. It's difficult to help without complete code. For example, maybe that "magic" is wrong maybe `buffer` doesn't contain what you think it does, etc. The actual parameter passing seems correct in terms of passing the buffer between the functions. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for further help.

Comment: I think @dbush has it: the pointers are all fine, but `%.2f` is an invalid format specifier for `*scanf`.  Do you not get a compiler warning about it? I do. (Do you not have compiler warnings enabled?!)  You probably just want `%f`.

Comment: @dbush I printed `val_buf` and confirmed that it contains a float string ("8.76" in my test case). Is that thing with the precision field also true for **s**scanf?

Comment: @SimSon Yes, all functions in the `scanf` family.

Comment: @kaylum I just confirmed that my buffers contain what I expected. Concerning the minimal reproducable example - yeah, I know that I should do that, but in my case the code involved is quite heavy. If I knew that my problem is not how I pass references I could search at a different point. Thanks for confirming that at least my passing is correct!

Comment: @NateEldredge no, I don't get compiler warnings and I tried with `%f`, but that didn't work as well... I'm compiling this for a Atmel microcontroller using `avr-gcc` and I don't have easily access to the serial line to get debug outputs...

Comment: Are you using `-Wall`?  I get a warning [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zTboWfGvb) with avr-gcc.  Have you checked the documentation for your library to make sure `sscanf` supports floats at all?  On a microcontroller it wouldn't be too surprising if it doesn't.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I now think it/I was wrong [_I_ had an off-by-one err]. Your code was correct. The limit can be `p < sizeof(val_buf) - 1` but that translates back to `p < 7`

Comment: Your passing of pointers into the function is correct [AFAICT]. If you're having a problem, this is due to the "magic" that sets the start/end indexes. As dbush mentioned, printing `val_buf` [just before the `sscanf`] should tell you want you need to know. You can also do a `printf` _if_ the `sscanf` returns 0 (e.g. `else printf("sscan failed on '%s'\n",val_buf);`)

Comment: We can help more _if_ you can _edit_ your post and show us the "magic" code. Also, what is the "raw" (pre "magic") string you're trying to parse?

Comment: @NateEldredge compiling with `avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -c -Os -Wall -mmcu=atmega168p main.c -o main.o` I get no compiler warnings (`avr-gcc --version` is 10.1.0). I know that floats are a bit special on microcontrollers, but I have set all neccessary linker flags (AFAIK) and I also use `sprintf` successfully with "%.2f"...

Comment: Oh, I wonder if your `stdio.h` lacks the magic `__attribute__` on its `sscanf` declaration to tell gcc to do format checking.

Comment: @CraigEstey printing `val_buf` reveals that it has the expected value. I'll try to put together a reproducable example if I don't get this to work soon...

Comment: I just noticed the Atmel/avr-gcc thing. To ensure it's _not_ some Atmel specific issue, you could build/run your MRE test program on your native [x86] development system. If _your_ code is the issue, the problem should show up there as well [and be easier to diagnose]. If the results are different on the two platforms, that will also say something.

Comment: @CraigEstey yeah, that's the next thing I will do. My suspicion was that I once again messed up with passing references as that was often my problem. Seems to be something different this time... I came up with a MWE, please see me second edit.

Comment: @NateEldredge I just included a MWE, please let me know if you see any problems with it ;)

Comment: This is evidently something specific to your platform, as it works fine on a generic C implementation: https://godbolt.org/z/h3qGh4r7o.  I'm going to add an AVR tag.

Comment: Some implementations have trouble with `scanf/printf` and floating point if there is no floating point _code_ in the rest of the code.  Perhaps after `printf("%.2f",testfloat);` append something like `testfloat = testfloat/7.0f;  printf("%.2f",testfloat);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already force the compiler to use the `printf` library **with** support for `float`, you know about this limitation of the standard library.

You need to do this for `scanf()`, too. See the documentation.

```
avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt -lm -mmcu=atmega168p main.o -o main.elf
```